# PHP Handling files - Delete uploaded files if form not submitted

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, image-uploading, file-handling

I have a form for the new offer/product. 
It has an images drag'n'drop field with draggable reordering possibility.
My question is:
What is the logic (steps) of handling uploaded files?
Specifically how to delete files uploaded by user, if he/she didn't submit the form? (Preventing storing unused files)

The scenario: user uploaded images, then after not submitting form (opening another link, closing window etc.) files will be deleted.

As an example I think of this:

1. Save uniquely named files in /tmp directory of site
2. Add info about them in $_SESSION var
3. If form submitted, move them to specific destination, else cron will clean up `/tmp` folder once per day

What is your suggestions?

Comment: The CRON solution seems fine to me if you allow enough time for the user  to finish the form.

Comment: `The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.` From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Or are we talking about multi-stage flows? "after not submitting" doesn't really make sense currently since an unsubmitted form wouldn't upload a file (without JS). Not enough specifics on how this is implemented.

Comment: Files are uploaded via ajax using Dropzone.js / fineuploader

Comment: @dmpol18 So how did you solve it? I have this same problem for years. Is there any other solution than CRON?

Comment: Any insight about this? I have this problem now!